# Different hash values of the same file (Reading done with ifstream)

Tags: c++, c++17

I've been trying to identify the problem for two days, so I could use some help. In short, I am a C ++ learner, I am practicing with a personal project: a very, very, very basic version control system.

**The application has 2 commands:** **`-catch`** and **`-look`**.

The  **`-catch`**  command allows you to register a new file to be tracked. Steps:

1. User (in console) accesses the root folder of his project, let's say **`C:\my_project\`**.
2. User enters the relative path of the file he wants to trace, let's say **`some_folder\my_file.txt`**.
3. The **`hash_builder`** function captures this path, locates and read the file, stores the content in a buffer, and generates a hash value of the file content.

**So far so good, we already have a file whose content has been represented by a hash value.**

On the other hand, the **`-look`** command allows to list the files in a folder and indicate if they are being tracked or not, or if they have been modified. Steps:

1. User executes **`-look`** command.
2. The file_classifier function starts to sort the files according to their status. To display the modified files, it calls the **`hash_builder`** function in order to calculate the hash value of a file and compare it with its previously calculated hash value. If the values ​​are different, it can be deduced that the file has been modified.

Here is the problem, **in SOME files the hash values ​​do not match even though the file has not been modified**.

To verify that the content reading is the same at every opportunity, I made the hash_builder function print each character that it is extracting from the file. To my surprise, the printed texts (one from **`-catch`** and one from **`-look`**) were different despite having been read with the same function and coming from the same unmodified file.

The **`hash_builder`** function here:

```
size_t hace_jach(string argument_file) {
    hash<string> hash_maker;
    ifstream argument_file_istrm;
    argument_file_istrm.open(argument_file, std::ifstream::in);

    int argumentfile_data_hash = 0;
    if (argument_file_istrm.is_open()) {
        argument_file_istrm.seekg (0, argument_file_istrm.end);
        int argumentfile_length = argument_file_istrm.tellg();
        argument_file_istrm.seekg (0, argument_file_istrm.beg);

        char* argumentfile_buffer = new char [argumentfile_length];
        argument_file_istrm.read(argumentfile_buffer, argumentfile_length);

        string argumentfile_data_container;
        for (int iterA = 0; iterA < argumentfile_length; iterA++) {
            argumentfile_data_container += argumentfile_buffer[iterA];
            cout << "Line #" << iterA << ": " << argumentfile_buffer[iterA] << endl;
        }

        argumentfile_data_hash = hash_maker(argumentfile_data_container);
        argument_file_istrm.close();
        delete[] argumentfile_buffer;

        return argumentfile_data_hash;
    } else {
        return argumentfile_data_hash;
    }
}
```

**I copy an example here:**

Original content of the file C:\test\why_do_you_hate_me_god.txt

```
Hello
World
```

Text printed by the **`hash_builder`** function applied to the file C:\test\why_do_you_hate_me_god.txt when running the **`-catch`** command:

```
Line #0: h
Line #1: e
Line #2: l
Line #3: l
Line #4: o
Line #5:
Line #6:

Line #7: w
Line #8: o
Line #9: r
Line #10: l
Line #11: d
Line #12:
Line #13:
```

Text printed by the **`hash_builder`** function applied to the file C:\test\why_do_you_hate_me_god.txt when running the **`-look`** command:

```
Line #0: h
Line #1: e
Line #2: l
Line #3: l
Line #4: o
Line #5:
Line #6:

Line #7: w
Line #8: o
Line #9: r
Line #10: l
Line #11: d
Line #12:
Line #13: «
```

As you can see additional characters appear at the end of each read **(sometimes one character, sometimes more)**, **this usually happens when there is a space at the end of the text and the text spans more than one line**, however what confuses me is that the additional characters are different in both cases. Shouldn't they be the same considering it's the same unmodified file and the same reading function?

Well this has gone on too long, if anyone has any feedback on this issue I would appreciate the help. I will continue investigating.

*P.S. Hacks to run the application are welcome, however I'm more interested in an opinion or explanation of why this happens.*

Comment: You don't check `read` for an error. You're opening the files as text (not binary, which requires the `ios_base::binary` flag), which can effect the character count. Possibly you're reading short and have uninitialized characters at the end of your buffer that you are processing.

Comment: This seems overkill for what is ultimately about dozen lines of simple code (header list not included), [e.g something like this](https://pastebin.com/bxKf6Beq). You can find more efficient ways, but if simple is the goal, at least that's what I would do.

Comment: Yesterday I saw that someone had sent a very useful comment with several tips on how to improve the code and a possible solution to the problem, I did not finish reading it because I was about to sleep. However, today I see that the comment is no longer ... If you are reading me, your comment seemed very useful, please put it back. Thanks!

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks, I will definitely review and adapt it right now to see if it fixes my problem. An additional question, could you explain why my code is deficient, finding the solution (your code) seems excellent to me, but I would also like to understand what my error is, and how your code solves it, sorry if it is too much to ask, but it would be very useful for someone of my level.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: "You're opening the files as text (not binary, which requires the ios_base::binary flag), which can effect the character count." 

Yes, precisely I read that yesterday, today I will be doing tests regarding this. Thanks.

Comment: `seekg` ultimately calls `std::fseek`, and `tellg` ultimately calls [`std::ftell`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/ftell). For the latter, "if the stream is open in text mode, the value returned by this function is unspecified and is only meaningful as the input to `std::fseek`"